# Gnuplot: Data blocks with different colours

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with multiple *blocks* in it, e.g.

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
x4 y4


x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
x4 y4


x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
x4 y4
```

And I'd like to plot each block to default to a different colour.  If each of these block were in a separate text file, this wouldn't be an issue as Gnuplot defaults to doing that.  Anyone know how I can get the blocks to each plot in a different colour (preferably regardless of how many blocks I have)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number of the data block is available as pseudo-column `-2`. Together with `linecolor variable` it gives you what you want:

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:-2 lc var with lines
```

With the data file:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4


1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5


1 3
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

you get the result (with 4.6.3):

[image]