# different colors for custom variable size points

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data points file which contains

```
1 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 3
```

Then I wrote this code (snippet) to draw a `variable size` points for 1 or 2 or 3

```
xcoord(N) = (N) 
ycoord(N) = (column(0)+1)
symbol(N) = strcol(N) eq "3" ? 3 : ( strcol(N) eq "2" ? 2 : (strcol(N) eq "1" ? 1 : 0)  ) 

set xtics ("2000" 2, "2001" 3, "2002" 4)
set ytics ("M1" 1, "M2" 2, "M3" 3)
plot for [N=1:3] 'data.txt' using (xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)*1) with points pt 7 ps var
```

Problem is all points have the same color. I want to use different colors for 1, 2 and 3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `linecolor variable` to select a line type (or line style) based on a data column, see the two recent questions [Gnuplot: Data blocks with different colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060558/gnuplot-data-blocks-with-different-colours) and [Gnuplot with both color and xtic from data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114688/gnuplot-with-both-color-and-xtic-from-data-file)

I'm not really sure, what the end result should be, but your example looks a bit strange. Why do you read the data as string and then convert it back to a number?

Just use

```
set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
plot 'data.txt' matrix using 1:2:3:3 lc var ps var pt 7
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that using `linecolor variable` will ignore the symbols and their size. It doesn't work with that example in my post

Comment: ? I took the data from your post, and as you see in the image, it works fine. I simplified the code, because I don't see any need in using `strcol` and your complicated symbol function. And your example doesn't show the `xcoord` and `ycoord` functions for testing.

Comment: Let me edit the post. I am sure that with the edited data, you will again see all points for all (x,y)

Comment: For me your exact script works fine with version 4.6.3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dyb0D.png You have different colors and sizes. Still I would suggest you to use `matrix` for plotting.

Comment: ok I will check that. Seems that there is problem with my scripts. thanks